# How to Format dict string outputs nicely

Tags: python, string, formatting

I wonder if there is an easy way to format Strings of dict-outputs such as this:

```
{
  'planet' : {
    'name' : 'Earth',
    'has' : {
      'plants' : 'yes',
      'animals' : 'yes',
      'cryptonite' : 'no'
    }
  }
}
```

..., where a simple str(dict) just would give you a quite unreadable ...

```
{'planet' : {'has': {'plants': 'yes', 'animals': 'yes', 'cryptonite': 'no'}, 'name': 'Earth'}}
```

For as much as I know about Python I would have to write a lot of code with many special cases and string.replace() calls, where this problem itself does not look so much like a 1000-lines-problem.

Please suggest the easiest way to format any dict according to this shape.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Depending on what you're doing with the output, one option is to use JSON for the display.

```
import json
x = {'planet' : {'has': {'plants': 'yes', 'animals': 'yes', 'cryptonite': 'no'}, 'name': 'Earth'}}

print json.dumps(x, indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{
  "planet": {
    "has": {
      "plants": "yes", 
      "animals": "yes", 
      "cryptonite": "no"
    }, 
    "name": "Earth"
  }
}
```

The caveat to this approach is that some things are not serializable by JSON. Some extra code would be required if the dict contained non-serializable items like classes or functions.

Comment: I would like to give you more then one up for this response. Just awesome! Thanks, man!

Comment: it doesn't work if one of the values is a Date object for example

Comment: How about the `None` object? It would be converted to `null`. You would convert those `null` objects to `None` manually.

Comment: I don't think this should be an acceptable answer because while json.dumps serialzies the dict, not all ptyhon objects are json serializable and the resulting string lacks proper formatting (as of this writting)

Answer (score 43):

Use pprint

```
import pprint

x  = {
  'planet' : {
    'name' : 'Earth',
    'has' : {
      'plants' : 'yes',
      'animals' : 'yes',
      'cryptonite' : 'no'
    }
  }
}
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(x)
```

This outputs

```
{   'planet': {   'has': {   'animals': 'yes',
                             'cryptonite': 'no',
                             'plants': 'yes'},
                  'name': 'Earth'}}
```

Play around with pprint formatting and you can get the desired result.

- http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html

Comment: Well, it has only depth, width and indent as parameters. I don't see a way to make planet go to the next line. Sure, PP results are better readable, but the newline+appropriate_spaces is nessesary for my case.

But thanks for showing me this nice package. Comes in very handy in other cases.

Answer (score 7):

```
def format(d, tab=0):
    s = ['{\n']
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = format(v, tab+1)
        else:
            v = repr(v)

        s.append('%s%r: %s,\n' % ('  '*tab, k, v))
    s.append('%s}' % ('  '*tab))
    return ''.join(s)

print format({'has': {'plants': 'yes', 'animals': 'yes', 'cryptonite': 'no'}, 'name': 'Earth'}})
```

Output:

```
{
'planet': {
  'has': {
    'plants': 'yes',
    'animals': 'yes',
    'cryptonite': 'no',
    },
  'name': 'Earth',
  },
}
```

Note that I'm sorta assuming all keys are strings, or at least pretty objects here

Comment: Works as expected. Anyway, I hope that somebody might find a all-batteries-included solution. If there is nothing else after the weekend, I use your solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Falls to infinite recursion on self-including dicts.

Answer (score 0):

here's some thrown together/temp code I'm using to do what's being asked, thought I'd share:

```py
v = {'has': {1: [213124,1243215,143541,531322], 'plants': 'yes', 'animals': 'yes', 'cryptonite': 'no'}, 'name': 'Earth'}
print(pretty(v))
```

output:

```
{
    'has': {
        1: [
            213124,
            1243215,
            143541,
            531322
        ],
        'plants{}': 'yes',
        'animals': 'yes',
        'cryptonite': 'no'
    },
    'name': 'Earth'
}
```

not pretty code:

```
def pretty(obj, starters='{[', enders='}]', items=','):
    _all = starters+enders+items
    tabs, i, s, inside_quotes = 0, 0, str(obj), ['"', False]
    def step_char(c):
        nonlocal tabs, i, inside_quotes
        tabs += (c in starters) - (c in enders)
        _c = (not (s[max(i-1, 0)] in _all and c == ' ')) * (('\n'+(tabs*'\t')*(c in set(_all)))*(c in set(enders))*(not inside_quotes[1]) + c + ('\n'+tabs*'\t')*(c in set(_all))*(not sum([s[i:].startswith(e+ii) for e in enders for ii in items]))*(not inside_quotes[1]))
        inside_quotes = in_quotes(i, s, inside_quotes)
        i += 1
        return _c
    return ''.join(list(map(step_char, s)))


def in_quotes(index, string, last):
    in_string = last
    for quote in ['"""', "'''", '"', "'"]:
        if string[index].startswith(quote):
            if in_string[1] and in_string[0] == quote:
                in_string[1] = False
                break
            elif not in_string[1]:
                in_string = [quote, True]
                break
    return in_string
```