# Python print() to resemble Jupyter Notebook output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, I can output a dictionary formatted nicely as:

```
type(study.best_params)
study.best_params
```

Output:

```
dict
{'learning_rate': 0.03432935238904508,
 'reg_lambda': 41.44611737822965,
 'reg_alpha': 67.05298367721595,
 'subsample': 0.5268673357670474,
 'colsample_bytree': 0.8097945252933975,
 'max_depth': 5}
```

When I print it:

```
type(study.best_params)
print(study.best_params)
```

Output:

```
dict
{'learning_rate': 0.03432935238904508, 'reg_lambda': 41.44611737822965, 'reg_alpha': 67.05298367721595, 'subsample': 0.5268673357670474, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8097945252933975, 'max_depth': 5}
```

Is there a way to print the dict nicely as the output ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Use `from pprint import pprint` and replace `print()` with [`pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Format dict string outputs nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733554/how-to-format-dict-string-outputs-nicely)

Comment: @SyedShahzer I don't think that answers OP's question since there is no mention about `JSON` whatsoever.

Comment: @accdias pprint did the job nicely.  Thanks very much !

Comment: @SyedShahzer I've tried print(json.dumps(study.best_params, indent=4)).  It works too !  Thanks very much too !

Comment: I've notice that the pprint methods changes the order of the dict while the json method does not.  Not that it matters to me, just an observation.  Again, thanks to both for answering my question.